# In how many was can you arrange 19 books on a shelf with 4 free book-places

Tags: combinatorics

There are 7 red books, 3 blue books, and 9 green books. There are 4 shelves, put at least 1 blue book on a shelf.

At the beginning I can put one of 16 books on a shelf, then I can put there one of the 15 books and lastly I can put there 14 books. For the last place I don't have a choice, but for each configuration of 4 books on a shelf I can shuffle the books, which is 4 times each configuration sums up to $134440$, possible ways. Is this the right way to solve this question correctly?

The difficulty here is that one could say at the beginning one has 19 books to place (including the 3 blue books), and then you could place 15, 14 and 13 books. So the question really is if you choose 19 books at the beginning do you choose one of the blue books or do you just choose a possibility of that book being there or both? Since if one chooses just a possibility, one doesn't know the configuration of the next step.

Comment: Hint: You could subtract the number of ways of placing only red and green books from the number of ways of placing all the books. Or you could count the cases with $1,2,3$ blue books separately.

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by "4 free book-places." Are you asking how many ways to take 4 books out of the 19 available books and arrange them on the shelf? Up to 4 books on the shelf? Something else?

Comment: @RoryDaulton It's about putting 4 books from 19 possible books on a shelf. One of the 4 books has to include a blue book.

Answer (score 1):

[assuming you meant the number of ways to select 4 books out of 19 s.t. at least one of them is blue].

1 blue book: you have three slots w'out blue books, you have 4 ways to fill the remaining 3 slots: rrr, ggg, rr, rgg

2 blue books: you have 3 ways to   fill two slots: rr, gg, gr

etc.

This assumes all books are the same and the order doesn't matter.

Comment: Do you mean $(19*18*17*14)-(16*15*14*13)$?

Comment: pls see the edit